# Authentication failed because remote party has closed the transport stream, need solution

Tags: c#, webproxy

Our VPC of company using an http system proxy. Due to the fact, there are no https proxy and any web links should using http proxy even it is a https.

I tried to add these two solutions to my C# code, but it doesn't help.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

or

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =  delegate (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) 
{ 
   return true; 
};
```

Some Details.

I also write a python code by O365 graph api python.

Solution is quiet simple.

Change connection.py source code from

```
if proxy_server and proxy_port:
            if proxy_username and proxy_password:
                self.proxy = {
                    "http": "http://{}:{}@{}:{}".format(proxy_username,
                                                        proxy_password,
                                                        proxy_server,
                                                        proxy_port),
                    "https": "https://{}:{}@{}:{}".format(proxy_username,
                                                          proxy_password,
                                                          proxy_server,
                                                          proxy_port),
                }
            else:
                self.proxy = {
                    "http": "http://{}:{}".format(proxy_server, proxy_port),
                    "https": "https://{}:{}".format(proxy_server, proxy_port),
                }
```

to

```
if proxy_server and proxy_port:
            if proxy_username and proxy_password:
                self.proxy = {
                    "http": "http://{}:{}@{}:{}".format(proxy_username,
                                                        proxy_password,
                                                        proxy_server,
                                                        proxy_port),
                    "https": "http://{}:{}@{}:{}".format(proxy_username,
                                                          proxy_password,
                                                          proxy_server,
                                                          proxy_port),
                }
            else:
                self.proxy = {
                    "http": "http://{}:{}".format(proxy_server, proxy_port),
                    "https": "http://{}:{}".format(proxy_server, proxy_port),
                }
```

System works.

Comment: "Due to the fact, there are no https proxy and any web links should using http proxy even it is a https." - how on earth does that work with any modern web-browser? So many pages with hardcoded `https` URIs (which _cannot_ be rewritten by a web-proxy server) will break...

Comment: If the problem is that HTTPS is unavailable (likely due to a horribly ignorant and misguided company policy), using `ServicePointManager` won't help you at all. The only _real_ solution is to violently bash in the head of whoever authored that policy - or at least secure an exception for this system.

Comment: I really don't want to use python cause O365 library in python is not offical by Microsoft and many apis are lost. I need to add those apis by myself.

Comment: Is your .NET code running on .NET Framework or on .NET Core (or .NET 5 or .NET 6, etc)?

Comment: Tried .NET 6 .NET 5 and .NET core 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For .NET Framework 4.x:

- If your program code runs on .NET Framework 4.x...
- **...and** if your program uses `HttpClient`, `HttpWebRequest`, or even the horrible `WebClient` class without any further trickery (e.g. custom `HttpMessageHandler` classes that do HTTPS-to-HTTP conversion themselves, or other attempts at implementing proxy logic)
- **then** you can specify a HTTP proxy in your `app.config` (or `web.config` if your application runs within IIS) [with the `<defaultProxy>` element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/defaultproxy-element-network-settings) and [one-or-more child `<proxy />` elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/proxy-element-network-settings):

```
<configuration>

    <system.net>
        <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="false">
            <proxy autoDetect="false" bypassOnLocal="false"  proxyAddress="http://your-proxy-server:1234" useSystemDefault="false" />
        </defaultProxy>
    </system.net>

</configuration>
```

### For .NET Core 3.0 or later, .NET 5, and .NET 6, and later:

- [.NET Core 3.0 introduced `HttpClient.DefaultProxy` to allow applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultproxy?view=net-6.0) to gain custom HTTP proxy logic by implementing [`System.Net.IWebProxy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.iwebproxy?view=net-6.0) themselves and and passing a reference into the `static IWebProxy DefaultProxy { get; set; }` property in `HttpClient` (ideally only once, during application startup).

  - [A default implementation exists in `System.Net.WebProxy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webproxy?view=net-6.0) which you can use without reimplementing `IWebProxy` btw.
- For (zero-code) configuration you cannot use `<defaultProxy>` in `app.config` as .NET Framework's traditional XML-based configuration feature was removed, instead you can configure process-wide HTTP/HTTPS proxy settings [by setting any of these environment variables](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29371): `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY`, `ALL_PROXY`, and `NO_PROXY`.

  - These environment variables are is documented on the same page as `HttpClient.DefaultProxy`.
  - Using those environment-variables will cause `System.Net.WebProxy` to be pre-configured and passed into `HttpClient.WebProxy` already for you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Add these two line codes at anywhere.

```
 Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTP_PROXY","http://your_proxy_address:port");
 Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTPS_PROXY","http://your_proxy_address:port");
```

Search sourcecode of "dotnet runtime" in GitHub is quiet difficult.

Comment: I'm not convinced this will work _unless_ your `SetEnvironmentVariable` calls happen before `System.Net.Http.dll` is even loaded - so you'd have to do this immediately inside `Main` (before `CreateHost`, `ConfigureServices` and `Run`), It's more reliable to use `setenv` or `export` in a shell-script that then starts the process instead of doing it in-proc.